# Stripping extension in a for loop

Tags: python, excel, glob, os.path

I am attempting to strip the .csv extension so that the file saves only as name.xslx instead of name.csv.xlsx but this does not seem to be working. I would appreciate some help. Thank you.

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import openpyxl
import os.path

#convert the csv to xslx
for csvfile in glob.glob(os.path.join('.', '*.csv')):
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.active
    with open(csvfile, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for r, row in enumerate(reader, start = 1):
            for c, val in enumerate(row, start = 1):
                ws.cell(row = r, column = c).value = val
    base = os.path.basename(csvfile)
    wb.save(base + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: `basename` is the full file name, it is the second item of `os.path.split`. use `os.path.splitext`

Comment: use text slicing `"filename.csv"[:-4]`

Answer (score 1):

Because `os.path.basename` doesn't do what you think:

```
>>> csvfile = "/path/to/my_file.csv"
>>> os.path.basename(csvfile)
'my_file.csv'
```

You *could* use `os.path.splitext`:

```
>>> os.path.splitext(csvfile)
('/path/to/my_file', '.csv')
```

Note bad, but a little unweildy. Personally, I've come to prefer `pathlib`:

```
>>> import pathlib
>>> p = pathlib.Path(csvfile)
>>> p
PosixPath('/path/to/my_file.csv')
```

It has a very nice OOP interface:

```
>>> p.name
'my_file.csv'
>>> p.suffix
'.csv'
>>> p.with_suffix('.xlsx')
PosixPath('/path/to/my_file.xlsx')
```

You can usually work directly with the `pathlib.Path` object, you can always get the string, though, if that is what your third-party library expects:

```
>>> str(p.with_suffix('.xlsx'))
'/path/to/my_file.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `basename()` use `base = os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0]`